# bashの特殊変数への代入にエラー

Tags: bash, shellscript

以下のsample.shをbashで動かした際に、変数を代入した特殊変数でエラーが吐かれます。
おそらく文字列として扱われているため、引数を引っ張ってこれていないのだと思いますが、何か対策はありますか。

```
[root@ test]# cat sample.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $2

echo ${2}

N=2
echo ${$N}

[root@ test]# sh sample.sh a b c
b
b
sample.sh: 行 8: ${$N}: 誤った代入です
```

Comment: `eval echo \${$N}` でしょうかね。

Comment: 日本語環境での `誤った代入です` というエラーメッセージは誤訳っぽいですね。 原文は `bad substitution` です。この場合、「代入」よりも「置換」がふさわしい語かと思います。

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $2

echo ${2}

N=2
echo ${!N}
```

とすることで、

```
 % ./sample.sh foo bar
bar
bar
bar
```

が実現できます。

Comment: 補記: Bash のマニュアルで indirect expansion と呼ばれている機構です。参考: ["3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)